# The 'username' key is missing from the given credentials array

Tags: php, laravel, active-directory, ldap

- Laravel Version: 9.11
- Adldap2-Laravel Version: 6.1.6
- PHP Version: 6.1.6
- LDAP Type: ActiveDirectory

**Description:**
I'm trying to Authenticate to my Active Directory with Laravel project. But i faced to this error message The 'username' key is missing from the given credentials array when i try to log in.

**Steps i've followed:**

1. composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel
2. Adldap\Laravel\AdldapServiceProvider::class,
3. Adldap\Laravel\AdldapAuthServiceProvider::class,
4. 'Adldap' => Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap::class,
5. php artisan vendor:publish
6. in the file ldap.php i made this changes

- 'hosts' => explode(' ', env('LDAP_HOSTS', '..*.*')),
- 'base_dn' => env('LDAP_BASE_DN', 'DC=host,DC=com'),
- 'username' => env('LDAP_USERNAME', 'Admin_username'),
- 'password' => env('LDAP_PASSWORD', 'Admin_password''),

7. auth.php

- 'providers' => [
  'users' => [
  'driver' => 'ldap', // Was 'eloquent'.
  'model' => App\User::class,
  ],

8. also ENV.

- LDAP_LOGGING=true
- LDAP_CONNECTION=default
- LDAP_HOST='...'
- LDAP_USERNAME=''
- LDAP_PASSWORD=''
- LDAP_PORT=389
- LDAP_BASE_DN="DC=*,DC="
- LDAP_TIMEOUT=5
- LDAP_SSL=false
- LDAP_TLS=false

9. then i use the command `php artisan adldap:import` it shows me that
   **Found 418 user** and when i want to import them **successfully imported
   / synchronized 0 user(s)** also i tested if the connexion is working
   with php native and that's worked.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: ok, well i'm trying to import users from active directory to my database and i used the commande "php artisan adldap:import" then it shows that "Found 418 user" but when  i want to import them it shows "successfully imported / synchronized 0 user(s) "